# Can not find "Error" view only happening in production and not test/dev

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5

In my code I put try catches around my code to try and handle errors and pass users off to an error page if I can't handle them. This works fine on my local development machine and when I publish to our test environment but once I publish to the production machine users are still given the old yellow error screen instead of being redirected to my error screen.

I have looked at the web.config files for both environments and the only difference is production has `<compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" />` and test has `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />`.

When I look at the error logs in production I get the error:

> The view 'Error' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ~/Views/Administration/Error.cshtml ~/Views/Administration/Error.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/Error.vbhtml

but doing a find of my entire solution in VS shows no code that redirects to a view called "Error". I am not sure what might be wrong here or how to go about fixing it. I am not sure what code/information may be of help here so if you need more details or code please comment and I will post it up.

Edit:
I should not that I am using ELMAH to get errors and the only error it is logging is for this missing view. And I have looked at the code that is ran under the path it indicates and the only thing that has the word "Error" in it is this line in my catch `return RedirectToRoute("Error Page");`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something like this:

```
public class AdministrationController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Error()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And `"Error Page"` is redirected to it. But you are missing the `.cshtml` file related to it.

I don't have enough information to find out why this happens only in production.

I would recomend you, instead of redirecting in a `try{}catch` closure, to do it inside the config like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

[Here](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs) you can find more information about it.

Comment: I have no action named error and no code that redirects to an action just called "error". I have an action called "ErrorPage" with the route name "Error Page" that everything redirects to.